# Appearance of words in Claims

Tags: claim-construction

In writing my Independent Claim is it necessary that every item term, nouns, identifying parts or processes of the invention be included in said Independent Claim? I currently have Dependent Claims introducing items not previously stated by using the phrase " further including".

Comment: https://patents.google.com/?q=CL%3d%22further+including%22&status=GRANT like these?

Answer (score 0):

The independent claim must include everything essential to the broadest conception of your invention. You can include other things if you want, but there is no need unless you're trying to avoid specific prior art that you're aware of.

As such, there is no need to include every feature in an independent claim.

As you suggest, dependent claims are for those features which are useful for your invention, but are not essential. Phrases like "further including", "further comprising", or "wherein" are quite common when introducing such features in a dependent claim.

Comment: I have in my Independent claim, ...utilize non-roll options...I have in my dependent claim, The method of claim 1, where in non- roll  comprise challenge passes, maximum gear speed...,

Comment: @AllanScottBarber Sure that sounds quite reasonable.

Comment: If you characterized any component as "critical" in the specification, the examiner may require it in all independent claims. So don't call anything critical for the invention.